Connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run with a NextJS/Prisma setup
Context
I'm developing a NextJS 14 application using google services.
I also use Prisma as my ORM, which works by having a DATABASE_URL (postgresql://postgres:password*^@IPaddress/dbname?schema=public")
Let me walk through my configuration.

I have a VPC network enabled, its called default and it has the basic configuration.
My SQL instance has private and public IP enable. For the private IP it is connected to my previous default VPC. Below It is how the networking tab looks like in my postgres instance 
Im my cloud Run instance I have again basic config. I set the Cloud SQL connections, by selecting my instance in the dropdown.

I also have the correct env variables using the Private IP
(provided in my SQL instance overview page) in the DATABSE_URL
variable (needed by Prisma). Below is how my networking tab looks like .


This is how the YAML in my trigger looks like. I had to pass here all my .env variables again because nextJS needs them for the build process. I'm also adding this line '--vpc-connector=default'

steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
      - '--build-arg'
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_URL=$_NEXT_PUBLIC_URL
      - '--build-arg'
      - DATABASE_URL=$_DATABASE_URL
      - '--build-arg'
      - RESEND_API_KEY=$_RESEND_API_KEY
      - '--build-arg'
      - JWT_SECRET_KEY=$_JWT_SECRET_KEY
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID=$_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
      - '--build-arg'
      - BUCKET_NAME=$_BUCKET_NAME
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_API_KEY=$_GOOGLE_API_KEY
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL=$_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
      - '--build-arg'
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=$_NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY
      - '--build-arg'
      - RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=$_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_DB_INSTANCE=$_GOOGLE_DB_INSTANCE
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_DB_PASSWORD=$_GOOGLE_DB_PASSWORD
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_DB_CONNECTION_NAME=$_GOOGLE_DB_CONNECTION_NAME
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_DB_NAME=$_GOOGLE_DB_NAME
      - '--build-arg'
      - GOOGLE_DB_USERNAME=$_GOOGLE_DB_USERNAME
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - >-
        --image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--vpc-connector=default'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - >-
    $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _AR_HOSTNAME: southamerica-west1-docker.pkg.dev
  _PLATFORM: managed
  _SERVICE_NAME: ******
  _TRIGGER_ID: ******
  REPO_NAME: ******
  _DEPLOY_REGION: southamerica-west1
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed
  - ******


The Problem
I get the error that It cannot communicate with the database
Can't reach database server at 172.18.160.4:5432
Which is the private IP and we are in cloud Run.
Hopefully, someone can help and figure out why I cannot reach my database
Below are the logs


Do not use the --vpc-connector, if you use the direct VPC egress feature. Replace it with these 2 lines: --network=default\n--subnet=default

Dear @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the response. The error is still happening and I did exactly what you said. Can't reach database server at 172.18.160.4:5432 . Let me know if you need any more info about the configuration I'm using. I'm doing the best I can , but still looks like It doesn't recognize the IP of the SQL instance. Do I have to give any special permission to the port? IDK, hopefully someone can help me figure it out

You can try to create a tiny VM in the VPC and check if the database set up is ok on the network. The target is to narrow the error location

Jonathan from the Cloud SQL team here.
It looks like the build process is trying and failing to connect to the database. If this is the case, you will need to configure Cloud Build to have access to your Cloud SQL instance.
See: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-build
Once the build process completes, then your application will start on Cloud Run, which you have already configured to connect to your database via VPC.

thanks @jonathan, I'm following the Configure Cloud Buid instructions (for Private IP). It is a step I missed before. In point 1, about creating a private connection, I'm using the already created 'default-ip-range', in point 2, I created a pool. After that, The error is still happening. still cannot reach my database in its private IP

@JoseFranciscoChavezCarreon, Can you get more detail from the logs? I'm wondering what kind of error is causing the "Can't reach database server at..." Is it: network timeout error, connection refused, unexpected closed connection, etc.
Also, confirm that you added your new private pool to the cloud build definition, which will cause the build to run on the private pool:
options:
  pool:
    name: projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/workerPools/private-pool

